# PEAR HTML_Template_IT/HTML_Template_ITX with PHP 7.4 result in empty page

Tags: php, pear

One of my projects utilizes the PEAR package HTML_Template_IT plus its extension HTML_Template_ITX. The code worked until a long overdue shift from PHP 5 to PHP 7.4. Now we're getting issues with referencing HTML_Template_ITX() from the extending class.
The implementation in a nutshell looks as sketched below:

```
<?php

//=== somesite.php ===//
[...]
$template = new siteMainTemplate("article.tpl");
$template->setCurrentBlock("ARTICLE");
$template->setVariable("ARTICLE_HEAD", "some headline");
$template->setVariable("ARTICLE_BODY", "some text");
[...]
$template->parseCurrentBlock();

$template->showSite();
[...]

?>
```

The class definition extending the PEAR package:

```
<?php

//=== classdefs.php ===//
require_once "../PEAR/ITX.php";

class siteMainTemplate extends HTML_Template_ITX {

  function __construct($pageBody, $pageTitle) {

    $this->template = $this->HTML_Template_ITX("../templates/");
    [...]

  }  // ... end of function

  function showSite() {
    $this->show();
  }  // ... end of function

}  // ... end of class definition

?>
```

This results in the error "Call to undefined method siteMainTemplate::HTML_Template_ITX()".

The line throwing the error is

`$this->template = $this->HTML_Template_ITX("../templates/");`

and it looks odd to begin with, but has worked for a very long time. Changing it to something like

`$this->template = new HTML_Template_ITX("../templates/");`

results in an empty/blank page - well, with errors turned on the following is really happening:

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Empty regular expression in /.../PEAR/IT.php on line 1020
Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression in /.../PEAR/ITX.php on line 296
Notice: Undefined property: siteMainTemplate::$parseCurrentBlock in /.../classes/classdefs.php on line ...
```

This clearly points towards a faulty class definition right there.

Can someone advice on what I am doing wrong here?

Edit: Typo corrected in second code snippet - the second function meant to complete the example as "showSite()", not as a second constructor function.

Comment: Does your `siteMainTemplate` class actually have two `__construct` functions or is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, a typo. Sorry about that - edited the original post. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Some more tests revealed the correct line is indeed:

```
$this->template = new HTML_Template_ITX("../templates/");
```

After that, the warnings posted in the question were simply covering up further inconsistencies rooted in handling of the "template directory" handed over.